# How do I combine tags in the UI?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see a way to specify multiple tags when creating or updating a question or answer, I see a way to click on a single tag and display messages with that tag, but I see no way to select multiple tags to narrow it down.

I can't believe the feature is really that broken. Isn't there a method to specify multiple tags? Why is the method so hidden?

Answer (score 2):

To combine tags

1. browse questions by tag
2. look for **related tags** area
3. click any tags in the related tags area to combine them with your current tag

[image]

Comment: Wow, you took the time to make a graphic and still beat me -_-

Comment: That's an AND search. I think that what was being asked for is an OR search. i.e. show me a list of questions containing any of my chosen tags as opposed to a list containing all of my chosen tags. I'd really like to see this too.

Comment: @robert so do it already; the functionality exists. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

Comment: Thanks! Maybe this should be made easier to discover?

Answer (score 1):

You just put a space between the tags:

```
foo bar
```

or, if you want to combine multiple words into a tag you can do

```
language-agnostic programming-languages
```